# Vector field in $\Bbb Q^2$ and $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, real-numbers, rational-numbers, vector-fields

I'd like to define a *weak vector field* in $\Bbb R^2$ that is tangential to a family of sine curves at each point. I define the family of sine curves as: $A_n\sin(x)$; $n=1,2,3,...$ and $A_n$ is a parameter; $A_n\in \Bbb Q^2.$ The vector field is weak in $\Bbb R^2$ but is complete in $\Bbb Q^2.$ I'm have trouble with finding the correct rational $A_n$ and expressing this vector field.

Edit: Viewing the family of sine curves as the solution curves to the differential equation: $y''+y=0$ with the initial condition as: $y(0)=0$ in $\Bbb R^2$ is helpful and seems help with the problem in $\Bbb R^2$. Not sure what to do about $\Bbb Q^2$.

I took Vector Calculus two years ago so I'm a little rusty. I know intuitively what to do but am struggling to capture this intuition in concrete notation.

*A weak vector field is basically a vector field with incomplete information. So there is not a vector at every single point in the vector field. Researchers study weak vector fields because they are easier to work with analytically.*

$1)$ Please be descriptive and rigorous in defining the vector field.

$2)$ Once one rigorously defines this vector field in $\Bbb Q^2,$ how does one take a kind of "limit" so as to make this vector field complete in $\Bbb R^2?$

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand you correctly. by „tangential to a family of sine curves“, you mean that you consider the _graphs_ of $x\mapsto A_n \sin (x)$, and want to study vector fields that are tangent to each point of the graph family (which wouldn't work at $y=0$), or do you mean something else?

Comment: So each curve $A_n\sin(x)$ is an integral curve

Comment: My confusion lies in the fact that the curve $A_n \sin x$ is a curve into the manifold $\mathbb R$, however you talk about $\mathbb R^2$ as the base manifold (and considering vector fields over that as the base space/manifold)

Comment: I think I might have made a mistake using $\Bbb R^2$. I think it would be better to say that the vector field is weak w.r.t. $\Bbb R$ and complete in $\Bbb Q$. does lowering the dimension make more sense?

Comment: @Luke thank you I made some edits to the question